# Test Flight Beta Testing: Xcode 6.3 Beta 4 does not show crashes

Tags: xcode, crash, xcode6, testflight, beta-testing

I'm focusing on the new Test Flight procedure. I developed an application (that I submitted through Xcode to the iTunes Connect portal) that crashes if a `UIButton` is tapped. Since, the application is available for Beta Testing to Internal Testers, I would expect to see a crash log within the new *Crashes* section of Xcode 6.3 Beta 4 (see [Crashes Organizer Help](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-crashes_organizer/_index.html)). But nothing. No crashes available.

Is there any particular reason for that? Is this related to the type of testers I'm using? I'm understanding that Xcode 6.3 is Beta version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**

Xcode 6.3 has been released and crashes are now available.

**Original answer**

From Apple documentation

> **How Crash Logs Are Collected and Aggregated into Crash Reports**
>
> Apple provides a service that collects crash logs from users and
>   organizes them into downloadable crash reports. However, crash logs
>   are collected only if you upload an app with the symbols. (In the
>   Archives organizer, select the “Include app symbols for your
>   application…” box when you upload your app to iTunes Connect.) For
>   apps released in the App Store, the user must also agree to share
>   crash logs with developers. TestFlight users automatically share crash
>   logs with developers. The service that creates the crash reports does
>   the following:
>
> - **Collects crash logs from both TestFlight** and App Store builds
> - Provides the total number of unique devices where the crash occurred
> - Provides a sample set of crash logs for each crash report
> - Removes all personal user data from the crash logs
> - Creates crash reports daily
>
> When you open the Crashes organizer, Xcode begins refreshing the crash
>   reports for your apps. Xcode downloads the top crash reports—crash
>   reports with the most number of occurrences on unique devices—that
>   occurred during the past two weeks. **However, there may be up to a
>   three day delay between when you first distribute your app and when
>   crash reports are available in Xcode.**

where emphasis is mine.

So I guess I need to wait.

Comment: flexaddicted: were u able to finally get the crash reports?

Answer (score 5):

When you submit a new build to iTunes Connect you will see [**THIS**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-archives_organizer/Art/upload_ios_app_2x.png) screen in organizer and you need to make sure the box is checked that says:

"Include app symbols for your application to receive symbolicated crash logs from Apple. "

When setting up an iPhone up for the first time you are asked [**THIS**](https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/iphone/iphone5s/ios8_set_up_app_analytics.png)

If you select "Don't Share" then the crashes won't be reported

P.S. I tried to show images in the post but I don't have any rep yet so it wouldn't let me, the best I could do was link to some images.

Comment: Both steps are already there. The second one can also be managed within the privacy section under Settings.

Comment: What about this? Important: Only a team agent or admin can view crash reports. Team members with an iTunes Connect account can also view crash reports.

Comment: I'm the admin within iTunes Connect (and in the Member Center).